# How to modify Mosquitto's Windows Firewall Inbound Rule to only allow connections from specific IP addresses?

Tags: security, mqtt, mosquitto, microsoft-windows, whitelisting

I am trying to set up IP whitelisting for my Mosquitto broker on Windows 7. To do so I have performed the following steps, based on this article: [How to Whitelist Your IP - Windows Dedicated](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/how-to-whitelist-your-ip-windows-dedicated).

1. Open **Windows Firewall With Advanced Security** from **Start**.
2. Select **Inbound Rules** from the list on the left.
3. Search for the rules called "mosquitto" there are 2-2 for TCP and UDP. (I do not know why there are two for each.)
4. Open **Properties** of the mosquitto TCP rule.
5. On the **Scope** tab, on **Local IP address** section select the **These IP addresses** and add the specific IP address. 192.168.1.5 in my case.

First I have received the following error.

[image: Picture of windows firewall error message reporting wrong parameter]

6. To solve it, the **Edge traversal** settings has to be modified on the **Advanced** tab. I have changed it from "Defer to user" to "Block edge traversal."

---

Conclusion. It does not work, I cannot connect to the broker from the 192.168.1.5 address. It is all the same if I select the "Allow edge traversal" option.

Once I switch back to the "Any IP address" my client connects without any problem.

What's wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better asked on Super User since it's basically a Windows Admin question?

Comment: @hardillb I have thought of that. But decided otherwise as I want to modify a specific mosquitto rule. I would like people to use this site when they want to set up a whitellist for their mosquitto broker. We already have a lot of question about mosquitto. I know, it is an overlapping question but I think it can get along.

Comment: There is nothing special about the mosquitto rule, it's just listening on a TCP port

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you make custom rule by typing the ports (1883 and 8883) and allowing separately with different rules both UDP and TCP on these ports.

See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947814(v=ws.10).aspx

[This](https://www.sevenforums.com/system-security/214964-firewall-rule-unable-change-scope-tcp-udp-rules.html) post says you need the described hack that did not work in your case to change the defaults by program name.